# Unhoisted variables (let, const) used in immediately invoked async function before declaration of said variables

Tags: javascript, safari, async-await, hoisting

Should the following code work?

```
(async () => {
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))
  useNum();
})();

let num = 10;
function useNum() {
  return num + 1;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/tayotitepa/edit?html,output

Safari on iOS (v13.3) says that it's impossible (`num` variable doesn't exist), whereas Chrome and Firefox think it's fine.

If you remove the `await new Promise...` line then Chrome and Firefox complain.

It seems like Chrome and Firefox are correct here, because we're not `await`ing the immediately invoked async function, and so by the time the `await new Promise...` line has finished, the rest of the script will have already been processed. But I thought I'd check because maybe the spec says that it's strictly about the *ordering* of the declaration of the variables and usages of those variables, and so it wouldn't matter about the "timing" of the usage of the variables.

Comment: I don't think the issue has anything to do with `async/await`. Safari is just wrong.

Comment: Also, `let` and `const` *are* hoisted; it just works differently than `var` hoisting.

Comment: Works fine on High Sierra's Safari

Answer (score -2):

I tried this with different scenarios, What I observed is that

1. async/await is nothing to do with this.
2. `let num` is hoisted but value is `undefined`.

so the code is look like something

```js
let num; // --- hoisted with value as undefined
setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)
console.log(useNum());

num = 10; // --- value is assigned here
function useNum(str) {
  return num + 1;
}
```

as you know java-script is synchronous, i.e it execute each and every line a at time, so when we are calling the `useNum` method at that time `num` will be undefined.

Comment: Your code is different than OP. It should be `setTimeout(() => {console.log(useNum()}, 1000)`